# Twig : unable to check if date is in last 2 years (prestashop)

Tags: date, if-statement, twig, prestashop

I have the following in one of my `prestashop.html.twig` files.

```
{% for order in customerInformation.ordersInformation.validOrders %}
    {% set mydate = order.orderPlacedDate %}
    {{ order.orderPlacedDate }} - {{ mydate }}
{% endfor %}
```

This works correctly and pulls the order dates of any orders and outputs e.g.

```
14/02/2019 - 14/02/2019
08/03/2018 - 08/03/2018
15/08/2017 - 15/08/2017
06/04/2017 - 06/04/2017
```

depending on how many orders there has been.

Now I want to check to see if the `order.orderPlacedDate` aka `mydate` is over 2 years old.

So I did:

```
{% for order in customerInformation.ordersInformation.validOrders %}
  {% set mydate = order.orderPlacedDate %}    

  {{ order.orderPlacedDate }} - 
  {% if date(mydate) > date('-2years') %}
    OK {{ mydate }}
  {% else %}
    Over 2 years ago {{ mydate }}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

but this results in a 500 error.

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (14/02/2019) at
>   position 0 (1): Unexpected character").

Tried changing the line

```
{% if date(mydate) > date('-2years') %}
```

to

```
{% if date(mydate) > date('-2years', 'Europe/Paris') %}
```

but that gave the error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string
>   (order.orderPlacedDate) at position 0 (o): The timezone could not be
>   found in the database").

Can anyone see anything wrong with the above?

p.s im very new to twig (as in just heard about twig today!) so please keep explanations as simple as possible :)

Comment: Verify the value for `order.orderPlacedDate`. Make sure a valid DateTime value is present!

Comment: What's your `twig` version? Run `composer show twig/twig` to find the exact installed version.

Comment: Hi, its a shared hosting platform so not sure how to find out twig version